How to Reset a Plot Without Using a Click?
I'm working on a simple program where I plot points on a graph by clicking. I also reset the graph (clear all points) by using the key combination Control + Shift followed by a click.
Here's the code snippet I'm using:
DynamicModule[{points = {}, resetFlag = False}, 
 EventHandler[
 Dynamic[Graphics[{If[resetFlag, points = {}; resetFlag = False;], 
 Point[points]}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
 Axes -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 ImageSize -> 400]], {"MouseDown" :> (If[
      CurrentValue["ControlKey"] && CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], 
      resetFlag = True, 
      AppendTo[points, MousePosition["Graphics"]]])}, 
 PassEventsDown -> True]]

In the above code, points are added to the plot by clicking. My question is: How can I change the logic so that resetting the plot doesn't require a click? I want to use a key combination to reset the plot without involving a click, to avoid accidentally adding points when trying to reset.
Any suggestions or implementation examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

One option is to add a separate button to reset the plot:
DynamicModule[{points = {}, resetFlag = False}, Column[{
   Button["Click to reset", resetFlag = True;],
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[
     Graphics[
      {If[resetFlag, points = {}; resetFlag = False;], Point[points]
       }, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Axes -> True, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 400]
     ], {"MouseDown" :> (AppendTo[points, 
        MousePosition["Graphics"]])}, PassEventsDown -> True]
   }]]



(+1) Very nice! I'll wait to see if anyone has another suggestion and I'll accept the answer.
